# Partially object loading in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a class that sometimes is not necessary to load fully. Can I load it partially, or I need to create light version of class (and new mappings for it)?

For example: class `Message` with `id, title, body, author, timestamp`. When I want to delete message i need only two fields `id, author`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a class that sometimes is not necessary to load fully. Can I load it partially, or I need to create light version of class (and new mappings for it)?

In theory, Hibernate can do *lazy property loading* if you use buildtime bytecode instrumentation. See [19.1.7. Using lazy property fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties). But I don't have much experience with that, I tend to prefer the *"light version"* approach *if* really required.

> For example: class Message with id, title, body, author, timestamp. When I want to delete message i need only two fields id, author.

This may not the best example as you could maybe use a [bulk HQL DELETE](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct) here (which is in general much more efficient than loading `Message` instances and looping over them to delete them). See the section [13.4. DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct). But if you can't, then loading an entity to delete it is the price to pay when using an ORM.